# Enable UIImagePickerController video compression

Tags: iphone, video, compression, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to enable video compression on video files recorded with UIImagePickerController?

When videos are selected from cameraroll with UIImagePickerController they are automatically compressed.

Are there any other way of compress a video? I've got access to the file with a NSURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to change the compression as it's being recorded.

You can set the videoQuality property of the UIImagePickerController to get a copy at a different bitrate.

For example "High" is: UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh = 0

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerControllerQualityType

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When a video is selected from cameraroll (thru UIImagePickerController) a progressbar is shown while the video is compressed. When a video is recorded by UIImagePickerController, the progressbar is never shown. I'm looking for a way to always compress the video.

Comment: CDeutsch is right. If you want the UIImagePickerController to compress the video more when recording set videoQuality to something lower than High. This will compress the video as you are recording. No need to wait on the progressbar to recompress it.